# How to interpolate a CSS property in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to create a Styled Component which can receive a prop for the type of border. The Section can either have `border-top` or `border-bottom` based on the prop passed to it.

Here is the code

```
type TSectionBorder = 'top' | 'bottom';

<Section edge="top">
  {children}
</Section>
```

How can I achieve this in styled components, something along these lines -

```
const Section = styled.section<{edge: TSectionBorder}>`
  border-${edge}: 1px solid black;
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const Section = styled.section<{edge: TSectionBorder}>`
  ${({ edge }) => `border-${edge}: 1px solid black`};
`;
```

I deconstructed the props just to keep your syntax, however, this is one way to do so. They also have a `css` helper to look into.

Documentation:

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props
https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css

Answer (score 0):

First you will import:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

Here is the function ButtonBlock:

```
    function ButtonBlock(props) {
        return (
            <BtnBlock type="primary" {...props}>
                {props.children}
            </BtnBlock>
        );
    }
    const handleColorType = (color) => {
       switch (color) {
           case 'grey':
              return '#D4D5D6';
           default:
              return '#6633CC';
       }
    };

    const hoverColorType = (color) => {
        switch (color) {
            case 'grey':
                return '#6a7581';
            default:
                return '#99CC00';
        }
    };
```

Styled Component:

```
const BtnBlock = styled(Button)`
    && {
        max-width: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-radius: 0;
        border: 0px;
        padding: 0;
        background: ${({ color }) => handleColorType(color)};
        &[disabled] {
            background-color: #c6c6c6;
        }
        :hover {
            background-color: ${({ color }) => hoverColorType(color)};
        }

        &[disabled]:hover {
            background-color: #c6c6c6;
        }
    }
`;
```